# error in def getPlayerMove(board): return int(move) indentation error

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading Michael Dawson's book [Python for the Absolute Beginner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1435459806). I have this code for Chapter 6 and when I ran the code and got the following errors:

```
in def getPlayerMove(board): return int(move) indentation error
return int(move) unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

How do I solve these?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#!/usr/bin/env python
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Tic Tac Toe game in Python
# Author: Mawuli Adzaku <mawuli@mawuli.me>
# Date: 20-05-2013
# Tested with Python 2.7
# TO RUN:
#         sudo chmod a+x tictactoe.py
#         ./tictactoe.py
# OR JUST RUN : python tictactoe.py
# @todo: parse user commands, log game scores, run game over telnet
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/local/bin/python
          # coding: latin-1
import os



# import modules
import random
import sys

import copy

def drawBoard(board):
    # This function prints out the board that it was passed.

    # "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    print('   |   |')

def inputPlayerLetter():
    # Lets the player type which letter they want to be.

    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be X or O?')
        letter = input().upper()

    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

def whoGoesFirst():
    # Randomly choose the player who goes first.
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'computer'
    else:
        return 'player'

def playAgain():
    # This function returns True if the player wants to play again,
    # otherwise it returns False.
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter

def isWinner(bo, le):
    return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or # across the top
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or # across the middle
    (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or # across the bottom
    (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or # down the left side
    (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or # down the middle
    (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or # down the right side
    (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or # diagonal
    (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) # diagonal

def getBoardCopy(board):
    # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
    dupeBoard = []

    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)

    return dupeBoard

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
    # Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
    return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
    # Let the player type in their move.
    move = ' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
        print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
        move = input()
     return int(move)
def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, moveList):
    possibleMoves = []
    for i in moveList:
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            possibleMoves.append(i)

        if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
            return random.choice(possibleMoves)
        else:
            return None

def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
    # Given a board and the computer's letter,
    # determine where to move and return that move.
    if computerLetter == 'X':
        playerLetter = 'O'
    else:
        playerLetter = 'X'

    # Here is our algorithm for our Tic Tac Toe AI:
    # First, check if we can win in the next move
    for i in range(1, 10):
        copy = getBoardCopy(board)
        if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
            makeMove(copy, computerLetter, i)
            if isWinner(copy, computerLetter):
                return i

    # Check if the player could win on their next move, and block them.
    for i in range(1, 10):
        copy = getBoardCopy(board)
        if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
            makeMove(copy, playerLetter, i)
            if isWinner(copy, playerLetter):
                return i

    # Try to take one of the corners, if they are free.
    move = chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
    if move != None:
        return move

    # Try to take the center, if it is free.
    if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
        return 5

    # Move on one of the sides.
    return chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [2, 4, 6, 8])

def isBoardFull(board):
    # Return True if every space on the board has been taken.
    # Otherwise return False.
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if isSpaceFree(board, i):
            return False
    return True

print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

while True:
    # Reset the board
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
    gameIsPlaying = True

    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'player':
            # Player’s turn.
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'computer'

        else:
            # Computer’s turn.
            move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
            makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):

            drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player'

    if not playAgain():
        break
```

Comment: It appears as though the return statement is indented one space too many in that function.

Comment: I've cleaned up language and whitespace in the above code, but I'm not sure of the correct spacing for the errors.  This code block is _very_ large.  Your question would be better received if you did more preparatory work to reduce it to a simpler example.  Often, this process (called "[rubber ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)") can provide you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getPlayerMove(board):
      # Let the player type in their move.
      move = ' '
      while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
          print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
          move = input()
       return int(move)
```

Exactly as the error says, you have an indentation error in the line `return int(move)`. It should have the same indentation of the `while` block.

Comment: ya indentation error return int(move) statement same as while also how to solve this..??@DeepSpace